# Anyone know how to replace the package scripts.vis for python with a new one? It was working in 2015

Tags: javascript, python, vis.js

In 2015 in the youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3JMhX1sT98U the scripts.vis package was used. I know the http://visjs.org for JavaScript. Anyone knows if still exists or knows a similar package?

Comment: Please accept your own answer if it answers your question. Please also describe what functionality you were looking for – otherwise this question should be removed from SO as an offtopic one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in: 
https://github.com/nicolewhite/neo4j-jupyter/blob/master/scripts/vis.py
You can follow the youtube video of Nicole White about Neo4j + Python Jupyter